# multiple imputation, lmer, and pooling ggeffects objects

Tags: r, lme4, r-mice, marginal-effects

I computed linear mixed effects models using lme4::lmer() on data that I multiply imputed using the mice package. On these lmer objects, I want to apply ggeffects::ggeffect() to get marginal effects that I can then plot for mean, +1sd and -1sd.

The [pool_predictions function](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/reference/pool_predictions.html) seems perfectly suited and does a great job for lm objects; however, for lmer objects the ggeffect() function does not work. ggpredict() for some reason works, but I want to get marginal, not conditional effects.

Here's a minimal reproducible example that I adapted from the pool_predictions() reference (the mixed model doesn't make sense, it's just to create an example):

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(mice,stats,lme4,ggeffects)
  data("nhanes2")

#First, the working example from the pool_predictions() reference, using an lm object and ggpredict():

  imp <- mice(nhanes2, printFlag = FALSE)
  predictions1 <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {
    m1 <- lm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl, data = complete(imp, action = i))
    ggpredict(m1, "age")
  })
  pool_predictions(predictions1)

#Now the same example, but using ggeffect() on the lm object, which also works:

  predictions2 <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {
    m2 <- lm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl, data = complete(imp, action = i))
    ggeffect(m2, "age")
  })
  pool_predictions(predictions2)


#It also seems to work for lmer objects, at least when using ggpredict():
    
    predictions3 <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {
        m3 <- lmer(bmi ~ age + chl + (1|hyp), data = complete(imp, action = i))
        ggpredict(m3, "age")
    })
    pool_predictions(predictions3)
    
#But when I use ggeffect() instead of ggpredict(), this doesn't work anymore for lmer objects.


  predictions4 <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {
    m4 <- lmer(bmi ~ age + chl + (1|hyp), data = complete(imp, action = i))
    ggeffect(m4, "age")
  })
  pool_predictions(predictions4)
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens or has any tips how I can get the pooled marginal effects for my lmer object?

Thanks a lot!

Antje

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this may be due to the way how data is retrieved from the environment, which fails for `ggeffect()` (which is based on the *effects* package). You could try `ggemmeans()` instead, which should give you the same results as `ggeffect()` does.